# Visual Studio : Create a app to point it a website.

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

OS : Windows-10 creators update. 
Visual studio community edition.

We have a website for which we would like to point to our visual studio app to. Is it possible in visual studio we can create an app where we have a container running our website. Currently I have installed visual studio and it's asking me for which modules of visual studio I should download. I don't want to install unnecessary modules.

Screenshot. 
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could create a C# windows forms application and add a webbrowser from the toolbox. in the properties window set the dock to fill it and then in the url box type the url and you're done.

Comment: Do I require these modules? https://s33.postimg.org/dlkphe7f3/modules.jpg Thanks.

Comment: The default modules should be enough for almost all use cases.

Comment: Total its downloading 15.18gb. Once its done on my 15mbps network, I will verify and mark your answer. Thanks.

Comment: I tried the way you suggested, but I cannot see the webpage. Does this webbrowser load JS as well. I want it to load all html, css and JS. What might I be doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Here is how it looks now : https://s17.postimg.org/9y5h5cesv/current.jpg

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to achieve maybe i have understood the question wrong.

Comment: I added the URL like you said in the webbrowser properties in bottom right. When I start the app and dock to fill. When I start the app, it gives me JS errors, but still I tell the app to continue. But after loading it shows me the screenshot I showed you. Also, when I right click, get the source, the source code matches our site, but it's not rendered.